# Unity - Firebase Functions are not being called on android

Tags: c#, android, firebase, authentication, unity-game-engine

**Just a month ago all the code bellow worked fine for me**. i could simply signup/login and use the real time database, until today..
i did everything as usually, **created a new Unity Project**, 
Switched the platform to **android**, **imported relevant Firebase SDKs** for unity, and copied the code bellow **which i used before without problems**. everything **ended with a successful build** on my old ***LG G2 mini***.
but with one little difference:

any of Firebase functions are not being called, **no crash, no freezes, no errors shown in Unity Editor, just NOT BEING CALLED and all code which comes after it.**

2 weeks i'm trying to resolve this, tried to debug APK at real time, but i found nothing.

```
private void Awake()
{
    //Just an example to save typing in the login form
    UserNameInput.text = "demofirebase@gmail.com"; // everything works until this line:
    auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance; // this function is not being called and everything goes after it doesnt work too. 
    PasswordInput.text = "abcdefgh";

    // Set up the Editor before calling into the realtime database.
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://testproject-69c2c.firebaseio.com/");

    // Get the root reference location of the database.
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

    SignupButton.onClick.AddListener(() => Signup(UserNameInput.text, PasswordInput.text));
    LoginButton.onClick.AddListener(() => Login(UserNameInput.text, PasswordInput.text));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems like there was something wrong with my 4 years old LG G2 Mini with Android Os 5.0.1. 
I've just tested everything on friend's Samsung and iPhone 5.
And afterwards everything worked fine on other 10000 different Android and iOs smartphones.